# Search for all bond with particualar fields in bbg terminal

Tags: bloomberg

Is it possible to get list of e.g. bonds from bbg terminal with some particular fields.

Example: Can I get list of all bond which has some particular day count convention, some frequency, a long first coupon, normal last coupon, which are fixed to float, etc...

Basically, I need search with filters.

If it is not possible directly through bbg terminal, is there an alternative way to perform such search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the function is `<SRCH>`, where it can be set different search criteria (based on available fields).

Answer (score 2):

How about you hit help twice on your terminal and ask bbg support directly ? Seems better suited to answer your question (and they are paid to answer you too)